# Using waterfall in map node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async.js

```
async.map(map, function(item, mnext){
    async.waterfall([
        function(wnext){
            console.log("1"); 
            //mongodb queryies something like
            db.collection.find().toArray(function(err){
                if(err){
                    wnext(err);
                }else{
                    wnext();
                }

            })
        },
        function(wnext){
            console.log("2"); 
            //mongodb queryies something like
            db.collection.find().toArray(function(err){
                if(err){
                    wnext(err);
                }else{
                    wnext();
                }

            })
        },
        function(wnext){
            console.log("3"); 
            //mongodb queryies something like
            db.collection.find().toArray(function(err){
                if(err){
                    wnext(err);
                }else{
                    wnext();
                }

            })
        }   



    ], function(err){
        if(err){
            mnext(err);
        }else{
            mnext();
        }

    })
})
```

I expected to see `1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3` based on the count of the map. But the situation is not as what I expected. I realize that it prints as `1 2 1 2 3 3` or something else than `1 2 3`. I couldn't understand how can this happen. Because it's waterfall and the structure is true I guess? So can we say that there is a problem about map or  waterfall? Or it async.map is asynchronous so it overwrite the waterfall?

I don't know.. and I'm stucked. What am I missing?? Isn't `1 2 3` is expected sequence?

Comment: You want [`.mapSeries`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapSeries)

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! you made my day.  I did not know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see `async.map` doc https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map,

> Note, that since this function applies the iteratee to each item in
>   parallel, there is no guarantee that the iteratee functions will
>   complete in order

Yes. `async.map` is parallel. To achieve what you want, use `async.mapSeries` https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapSeries